# form_widget doesn't display invalid_message errors

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, error-handling, password-confirmation

I ran into an issue when I try to `render an error message` associated to a `repeated password field`. The issue is the `invalid_message` does not get rendered if I implement the twig as follows,

```
     {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal', 'role': 'form', 'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
        <div class="form-group {% if form.password.vars.errors|length > 0 %}has-error{% endif %} {% if form.password.vars.required == 'true' %}required{% endif %}">
          {{ form_label(form.password.first, "Password") }}
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            {{ form_widget(form.password.first) }}   
            <span class="help-block">{{ form_errors(form.password) }}</span>
          </div>              
        </div>

        <div class="form-group {% if form.password.vars.errors|length > 0 %}has-error{% endif %} {% if form.password.vars.required == 'true' %}required{% endif %}">
          {{ form_label(form.password.second, "Confirm password") }}
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            {{ form_row(form.password.second) }}

          </div>
        </div>
        ........
```

However, If I use `form_row`,

```
     {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal', 'role': 'form', 'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
        <div class="form-group {% if form.password.vars.errors|length > 0 %}has-error{% endif %} {% if form.password.vars.required == 'true' %}required{% endif %}">
          {{ form_label(form.password.first, "Password") }}
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            {{ form_row(form.password.first) }}   
            <span class="help-block">{{ form_errors(form.password) }}</span>
          </div>              
        </div>

        <div class="form-group {% if form.password.vars.errors|length > 0 %}has-error{% endif %} {% if form.password.vars.required == 'true' %}required{% endif %}">
          {{ form_label(form.password.second, "Confirm password") }}
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            {{ form_row(form.password.second) }}

          </div>
        </div>
        ........
```

The error gets displayed on top of the password text box (which is not the area I placed the error as the `span` is actually below the textbox) and also without highlighting the textbox. I tried my best to resolve this but no luck. I would be really grateful if you experts could provide any expert guidance to resolve this issue. :)

**FYI** : the repeated password on the form controller

```
$builder->add( 'password', 'repeated', array( 'type' => 'password', 
                                      'required' => true,
                                      'invalid_message' => ErrorMessages::PASSWORDS_DONOT_MATCH,
                                      'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field form-control')),                                                                                   
                                      'first_options'  => array('label' => false,                                                                    
                                                                'label_attr'=>array('class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label')),
                                      'second_options' => array('label' => false,                                                                    
                                                                'label_attr'=>array('class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label'))));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was simple and am posting this in case anyone runs into this issue in the future. The solution is to render the fields using the `forms_row` eg: `{{ form_row(form.password.first) }}` and include `'error_bubbling' => true` to the field where you want the error to be displayed. Inclusion of this solved the issue of field highlights and error message placements which in my case I displayed the error under the `first password text box`.

working example,

- the `twig`

  ```
   {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal', 'role': 'form', 'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
      <div class="form-group {% if form.password.vars.errors|length > 0 %}has-error{% endif %} {% if form.password.vars.required == 'true' %}required{% endif %}">
        {{ form_label(form.password.first, "Password") }}
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          {{ form_row(form.password.first) }}   
          <span class="help-block">{{ form_errors(form.password) }}</span>
        </div>              
      </div>

      <div class="form-group {% if form.password.vars.errors|length > 0 %}has-error{% endif %} {% if form.password.vars.required == 'true' %}required{% endif %}">
        {{ form_label(form.password.second, "Confirm password") }}
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          {{ form_row(form.password.second) }}

        </div>
      </div>
      ........
  ```
- the `form` controller

  ```
  $builder->add( 'password', 'repeated', array( 'type' => 'password', 
                                        'required' => true,
                                        'invalid_message' => ErrorMessages::PASSWORDS_DONOT_MATCH,
                                        'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field form-control')),                                                                                   
                                        'first_options'  => array('label' => false, 
                                                                  //here I enable error bubbling so that on the twig it will render the error under the first password text field 
                                                                  'error_bubbling' => true,
                                                                  'label_attr'=>array('class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label')),
                                        'second_options' => array('label' => false,                                                                    
                                                                  'label_attr'=>array('class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label'))));
  ```

Comment: thank you, I saw the correct errors in my console when debugging but could not figure out why it was not showing on screen. For me I was only missing the `'error_bubbling' => true`